# Unable to use inherited_resources' polymorphic belongs_to with namespaced controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, inherited-resources

I am facing an issue with inherited_resources when using a polymorphic nested resource, one of whose parents is a namespaced controller. Here is an abstract example:

```ruby
# routes.rb
resources :tasks do
  resources :comments
end   
namespace :admin do
  resources :projects do
    resources :comments
  end
end

# comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :projects, :tasks, :polymorphic => true
end
```

When I access `/admin/projects/1/comments`, I get this error:

```ruby
ActionController::RoutingError at /admin/projects/1/comments
uninitialized constant Admin::CommentsController
```

Now if I define the controller as `Admin::CommentsController`, I would need to move the file under `controllers/admin` which will in turn throw up an error for the url `/tasks/1/comments`

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep `CommentsController` where it is and make a separate controller for admin in `admin/comments_controller.rb?` that inherits from it?

```
class Admin::CommentsController < CommentsController
   before_filter :do_some_admin_verification_stuff

  # since we're inheriting from CommentsController you'll be using
  # CommentsController's actions by default -  if you want
  # you can override them here with admin-specific stuff

protected
  def do_some_admin_verification_stuff
    # here you can check that your logged in used is indeed an admin,
    # otherwise you can redirect them somewhere safe.
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes this is one solution but was trying to see if I could DRY up the `CommentsController`, which is the basic purpose of `inherited_resources`. If not, I'll have to write a concern and include that in both the comments controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is mentioned here in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use).

Basically you have to tell the route mapper which controller to use because the default is not there:

```
#routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :projects do
    resources :comments, controller: 'comments'
  end
end
```

That will take care of your routing problem, which is actually probably not related to `Inherited Resources`.

On the other hand, I have been unable to use `Inherited Resources` as well, in cases of a nested controller inside a namespace.  I've moved away from that gem because of this.

I created something that might be interesting to you: a [controller concern](https://gist.github.com/tylergannon/0b63979299f8f031e7e8) that will define all of the useful route helpers that inherited resources gives, in a way that accounts for namespaces.  It's not smart enough to handle optional or multiple parentage, but it spared me a lot of typing long method names.

```
class Manage::UsersController < ApplicationController
  include RouteHelpers
  layout "manage"
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
  before_action :load_parent
  before_action :load_resource, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :js

  create_resource_helpers :manage, ::Account, ::User

  def index
    @users = parent.users
    respond_with [:manage, parent, @users]
  end

  def show
    respond_with resource_params
  end

  def new
    @user = parent.users.build
    respond_with resource_params
  end
  #  etc...
end
```

And then inside my views:

```
    td = link_to 'Show', resource_path(user)
    td = link_to 'Edit', edit_resource_path(user)
    td = link_to 'Destroy', resource_path(user), data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete
```

Hope that helps!